# Angular: Using directives with *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-ng-if

Is it somehow possible to say if `i >= 2` then `[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[one, two]"`, otherwise `[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[three, four]"`?

`*ngIf` didn't work for me.
I also searched for "Angular ngif directives". However, the answers I was looking for did not come out.

```
<div *ngFor="let task of this.tasks; let i = index">
    <div>
        <div
            cdkDropList
            id="task-container-{{i}}"
            #ref{{i}}="cdkDropList"
            [cdkDropListData]="task.getDropListData()"
            [cdkDropListConnectedTo]= "[]"
            (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            <div>
                <p>{{task.getHeadline()}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I understand what you try to do, you are assigning the value based on condition. `[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="i >= 2 ? [one, two] : [three, four]"`. `*ngIf` is used for rendering the element by condition.

Comment: what is `one, two` in `[one, two]` ? Is this array of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question, you are assigning the value based on the condition.
You can achieve with:

```
[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="i >= 2 ? [one, two] : [three, four]"
```

`*ngIf` is used to render the element or not by the condition. Hence `*ngIf` is not suitable in your scenario.

Unless you are attempting with [`*ngIf with else`](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-ngif-else-then) template as:

```
<div *ngIf="i > 2; else elseTemplate"
  cdkDropList
  id="task-container-{{i}}"
  #ref{{i}}="cdkDropList"
  [cdkDropListData]="task.getDropListData()"  
  [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[one, two]"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  ...
</div>

<ng-template #elseTemplate
  cdkDropList
  id="task-container-{{i}}"
  #ref{{i}}="cdkDropList"
  [cdkDropListData]="task.getDropListData()"
  [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[three, four]"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  ...
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I get a parse error when using task-container-{{i}} in the ngIf. [cdkDropListConnectedTo]= "i >= 2 ? [task-container-{{i}}] : [three, four]"

Comment: No, that is not the correct way. `[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="i >= 2 ? [one, two] : [three, four]"`

Answer (score 1):

Bind a function like this:

```
[cdkDropListConnectedTo]= "getDropList(i)"
```

Now inside your ts file, create the callback:

```
getDropList (i) {
 return i >= 2 ? [one, two] : [three, four];
}
```